# Sharing gettext .mo file between multiple servers

Tags: php, gettext

I just started using gettext for php yesterday.

I created a .po file locally using poedit.  (ubunt 12.04 64bit).  I put this file and the compiled .mo file under version control because I plan on deploying to the production version of the site, which runs on rackspace cloud sites.

My question is:

**Is .mo file platform dependent?  Will it work on any server? If not how is this usually handled? The issue is there is no shell access to cloudsites so if I need to recompile it or something it will be a pain.**

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can redistribute mo files among servers. The mo files are actually read by the apache webserver, and not by PHP.

Be aware however, that if your mo uses a locale that is not installed on the underlying os, your mo files will not work.